# I have this type of error while iterate arrary in for loop "panic: runtime error: index out of range"

Tags: arrays, for-loop, go, iteration

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
)
func main() {
    var a int
    var b int
    
    var ar [] int
    fmt.Scan(&a)
    
    for i:= 1; i<a; i++ {
        fmt.Scan(&b)
        ar[i] = b
    }
    
    fmt.Print("Hello")
    for i:= a; i>0; i-- {
        b = ar[i]
        fmt.Print(b)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Corrected code, I think it's what you want

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var a int
    var b int

    fmt.Scan(&a)

    // make slice with len a, cap a, 0 filled
    ar := make([]int, a, a)
    for i := 0; i < a; i++ {
        fmt.Scan(&b)
        ar[i] = b
    }

    fmt.Print("Hello")
    for i := a - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        b = ar[i]
        fmt.Print(b)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i:= 1; i<a; i++ {
        fmt.Scan(&b)
        ar[i] = b
    }
```

`ar` is empty. If you want to add something, then use `ar = append(ar, ...)`

Or create `ar` with the correct size: `ar = make(int[], a)`. Then ar will contain several zero values.

Answer (score 0):

2 possible solution. 1 making use of an **array** the other making use of a **slice**

When to use an array (When u know the exact size of your array):

Declare your array as   `ar := make([]int, a)` this assume size of array is `a`

---

When to use slice (When u are not sure of the exact size or it may be expanded):

Append to your array like this: `ar = append(ar, b)`